# Does amplify remove auth affect all environments?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I want to remove auth from only 1 single Amplify environment (production) using `amplify remove auth`.

Does this command affect all environments?

Would it delete every user pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`amplify remove auth` will delete the authentication service locally from the currently checked out environment.

To find out your current environment, run `amplify status`. If this is the wrong environment, run `amplify env list` and then `amplify env checkout ENV_NAME` to switch to the right one.

Running `amplify remove auth` will then not touch any other auth related stacks (e.g. user pools etc.) for any other environments. It will only impact the current env.

Subsequently, run `amplify push` to update your cloud configuration once happy.